# Logical operations with defined conditions

Tags: conditional

I'd like to know how to define logical conditions to manipulate them. For example, say I have a list `list` of pairs of numbers, and I want to Select those which satisfy some condition

`cond = #[[1]] > 0 &;`

Then I just have to evaluate `Select[list, cond]`and it works. But if I have several conditions

`cond1 = #[[1]] > 0 &;
 cond2 = #[[2]] > 0 &;`

then both `Select[list, cond1 && cond2]` and `Select[list, cond1 || cond2]` always give an empty list. How do I have to combine the conditions inside `Select[ ]` so that it understands the logical connection between them ( AND or OR)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
Select[list, Through @* And[cond1, cond2]]
```

For example:

```
Select[Range[10], Through @* And[PrimeQ,EvenQ]]
```

> {2}